# First of all, I love flowers

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> First of all, I love flowers,
>   At my cottage in the country I grow many,
>   Lovely blue ones, beautiful yellow ones,
>   And most of all orange tulips!
>   Of course I grow vegetables too,
>   And I also cook,
>   Red beet soup, carrot cake,
>   And plenty of casseroles,
>   A short ways from my cottage is a grand farmers market,
>   And whenever they are in town I buy many fruits.
>   Peaches are my favorite!
>   At 4:30 every Friday I bake my husband a peach cobbler.
>   Often it is gone in a day!
>   At 12 every week day I bring fresh goods to my bakery down the road.
>   Lots of people come there for a little lunch treat.
>   After that I bring some pies to my grandparents.
>   Issac my grandfather was the one who taught me to bake.
>   Aside from all of that I still love flowers!
>   So this is me.

Who am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> April's Fool?

Because

> if you ignore all but one of the "A"s starting each line, these are the letters that are left (after rearranging).

Comment: You got it :D Good job